# AS3 Parallax speed

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating an AS3 game which will be ported to iOS and I am using the parallax feature but I can't get a layer to go any slower than 0.1. Is that the slowest it will go or is there a way to make it slower still?

I want a sky layer to go 0.05 or slower.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you completely understand the mechanism

**The idea:**

- The speed is given by the number of pixels moved in a frame and framerate. if you have a fps of 50, and a speed of 0.02 then your game should move the background 1 pixel in 1 second.
- Since 1 pixel is the minimum unit you can move, moving the background by 0.1 or 0.0000001 pixels will not affect at all the view until the unit is reached (for user x=12.1212 is same as x=12.1213). Sure we must exclude any anti-aliasing.

**So, as an answer:** setting any speed should work!

**Suggestion:** when you set x, y, width and height properties, convert the values to **int** for **performance** reasons. Anyway if you do not use any level of anti-aliasing the visual result will be the same.